# How to port following hook to reasonml

Tags: reason, reason-react

I have following custom hook

```js
function useConstant(fn) {
  const ref = React.useRef()

  if (!ref.current) {
    ref.current = fn()
  }

  return ref.current
}
```

and it seems quite hard to port this to reasonml, I have to use type cast twice, what's the ideal way?

```
external toAny: 'a => 'b = "%identity";
external toBool: 'a => bool = "%identity";

let useConstant = (fn: unit => 'a) => {
  let ref: React.Ref.t('a) = toAny(React.useRef());
  if (!toBool(React.Ref.current(ref))) {
    React.Ref.setCurrent(ref, fn());
  };
  React.Ref.current(ref);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the purpose of the hook correctly, it's really just a reimplementation of `React.useMemo`. But for the sake of learning, here's an implementation that should work.

```rust
let useLazy = (fn: unit => 'a): 'a => {
  let ref = React.useRef(None);

  switch (React.Ref.current(ref)) {
  | Some(value) => value
  | None =>
    let value = fn();
    React.Ref.setCurrent(ref, Some(value));
    value;
  };
};
```

It uses [the option type](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/null-undefined-option), which is specifically designed for cases like this. If there's no value, we represent that using `option`s `None` value, and if there is a value we use `Some`. Instead of using `if` with JavaScript's semantically unclear concept of truthiness, we [pattern match](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/pattern-matching) on the `option` using `switch` to find that it's `None` and the value needs to be computed, or `Some` to get at the value.

The use of `option` and pattern matching is really common in Reason code, so it's one you should really try to understand using the links provided above for more details if needed.

Note that you could also have used [`Lazy`](https://reasonml.github.io/api/Lazy.html) for this. But that's far less commonly used and therefore also much less useful to learn.

Comment: Yes, it's basically `useMemo` except [You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

Comment: However your answer doesn't seem to [compile](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=DYUwLgBArgziAyBDAXgTwgXggCgGYDsAuafAS0gwD4IByRASk2oG8AoCCUSAJxF0wgAlEIgDGYAHSwQw3NgByAe3wh6AblbsIMAO7lRACxzCxk2RNFRuvfGGy9c9Rmw4AfCEpVMhI8RPNwYADCVjZ2DgA0EADKigC2IHj42E7qWu6xCdgAbojAUKreufkgWgC+GhWaXBCIAtJIaNgp3gCMAAz0QA)

Comment: What's wrong with it? I tried it in the Reason playground, but apparently React, or the React example, is broken there. It did seem to get past type checking the hook though.

Comment: Also, if you rely on side-effects you shouldn't use this either, but `useEffect` instead.

Comment: In my local project your `useLazy` is also inferred as `unit => unit => unit`, while it should be `unit => 'a => 'a`

Comment: Ah, sorry. `React.Ref`setCurrent` of course doesn't return the value after setting it. It returns `unit` so that's what the value is inferred to be as well. I've updated the answer with one that should hopefully work properly.